# How to run code in Flask APP after it finishes initializing ("Running on htttp://127.0.0.1:5000/...)

Tags: python, flask, webdriver, runtime

I am writing a Flask application to run on a local machine and do some things.  I want my flask application to automatically open the web browser once it finishes initializing.  The problem is that when I package it all together, sometimes the webdriver loads much faster than the Flask APP is able to initialize.

I have tried time delays and threading, but for the most part I keep getting inconsistent results.  I have tried using Flask's @before_first_request, but that is still once a request has been put in from the browser.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    port = 5000 + random.randint(0, 999)
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:{0}".format(port)

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    # options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--kiosk")
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    # threading.Timer(5, lambda: browser.get(url)).start()
    browser.get(url)

    app.run(port=port, debug=Flase)
```

I expect the actual webdriver to open AFTER Flask has finished initializing.  I can't put it after app.run because that starts the flask "loop" and will not execute.  Is there any function to run once Flask has fully initialized but not yet accepted any requests?

Thanks!

Comment: Try multiprocessing (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) and run your dev server and browser in  seperate processes

Comment: adding on what altunyurt said, you could make a ping request to your webserver from the second process, just like a health check to assure if the server is up and running. after you get a first 200, you start your browser

Comment: This seems reasonable guys.  I appreciate the input.  With multiprocessing and whatnot, could I link the two processes somehow?  For example, a @app.redirrectToMyPage section of flask code that would interact with the webdriver process?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any function to run once Flask has fully initialized but not yet accepted any requests?

Try registering a callback for `before_first_request`:

```py
@app.before_first_request
def run_browser():
    # ...
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request

Comment: I have tried this, and this still executes only once a browser is opened and a request is put it.  Kindof like a pre-request function.